# While in a for loop causing server to return error

Tags: php, function, for-loop, while-loop

I am writing a `php` script that will generate a random 16-digit string (containing both numbers and letters). It will create as many strings as the user tells it to, via a number input type in a form.

I wrote a for loop to handle executing code x amount of times (how many times the user tells it to via form), but putting the while loop in my for loop is causing a `500 Internal Server Error`.

`$generate_num` is what the user provides through the form.

Here is what I am working with:

```
for($x = 0; $x <= $generate_num; $x++){
    function makeString() {
      $salt = "abchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
      srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
      $i = 0;
      while ($i <= 15) {
          $num = rand() % 33;
          $tmp = substr($salt, $num, 1);
          $string = $string . $tmp;
          $i++;
      }
      return $string;
    }

    $string = makeString();  
}
```

I have ran my code on a PHP error checker website, and it didn't say I had any errors. Any insight on why this could be giving a 500 server error would be tremendously appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You defind the function much times in the foo loop

Comment: Also note that you should only call `srand()` once, and what you call `$salt` has nothing to do with a cryptographic salt. I hope you are not trying to use the result for cryptographic purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a function in the loop. It's invalid syntax, run the code on any IDE or local machine so that you can get an idea.

500 is internal server error, you can check out the apache logs to get a better idea.

You can make it work like this:

```
    function makeString() {
      $salt = "abchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
      srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
      $i = 0;
      while ($i <= 15) {
          $num = rand() % 33;
          $tmp = substr($salt, $num, 1);
          $string = $string . $tmp;
          $i++;
      }
      return $string;
    }

    $generate_num= 5;
    for($x = 0; $x <= $generate_num; $x++){
        $string = makeString();  
        echo $string. "<br/>";
    }
```

Comment: Can you not declare a function in a loop? Sorry if that's a stupid question, don't work with loops all that much. I am running this website on a local machine for now, and got that error.

Comment: check out my code. you are declaring a same name function using a loop which is not allowed in php.

Answer (score 3):

you should define your function outside of your loop. Although it isn't invalid, it will create a new function ever time the for-loop loops (which isn't necessary and you can't redeclare functions).
Also your $string variable must be passed to the function as argument or via `use ($string)`. Now the function doesn't have access to the variable.

```
$string = '';

for($x = 0; $x <= $generate_num; $x++){
    $string .= makeString();  
}

function makeString() {
    $string = '';
    $salt = "abchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= 15) {
        $num = rand() % 33;
        $tmp = substr($salt, $num, 1);
        $string = $string . $tmp;
        $i++;
    }

   return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare a same function in the for loop many times, which will caused

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare makeString()

Beside that, you have an undefined `$string` variable in your code which will cause a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
function makeString() {
  $salt = "abchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
  $i = 0;
  while ($i <= 15) {
      $num = rand() % 33;
      $tmp = substr($salt, $num, 1);
      $string = $string . $tmp;
      $i++;
  }
  return $string;
}

for($x = 0; $x <= $generate_num; $x++){
    $string = makeString();  
}
```